# child controls disappear when running already running app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

bit of a strange one... when my app is running I add a custom control to a StackPanel on the click of a button like so...

```
void btnAddPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PlayerControl sbItem = new PlayerControl();
   ctlPanel.Children.Add(sbItem);
}
```

(ctlPanel is a StackPanel PlayerControl is a standard Control inherited from UserControl)

So I add one or two, not a problem... if I multi-task on the phone to a different app, then multi-task back to my app, not a problem... however, if I multi-task away (or hit the windows phone button) and then instead of multi-tasking back, I just click on the icon (as if Im running the app again) it reloads my app but without any PlayerControl's in the StackPanel ... and while debugging, it doesnt hit the InitializeComponents() method in the pages constructor (of course this could be because it might not debug it when you run it straight from the menu)

Anyone know if theres a way to only allow an app to be run once (and dont restart it if the user runs the app again)????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work that way. You can save the "state" of your app and load that when you start the application. Look at "Tombstoning" for windows phones. Example, you can save in the local storage the current screen id and any other necessary data and when you launch the app, if you have something in local storage you load that screen, else you start with your homepage.

Comment: ah ok .. so basically i have to save the state everytime i do anything? otherwise is there an event to tell me that the app is being restarted?

Comment: Yes, I am sure there are events, off the top of my head there are events like Application_Deactivated, Application_Activated, Application_Launching, etc.